# In AngularJS, is there a way to set the size of a <select> element with scope value?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJS, I'm setting HTML form elements with some data inside $scope.

```
<select  style='width:300px' size='10' ng-model='selected' ng-options='k as v for (k,v) in options' />
```

In this example, size is set to 10. But I would like to set it according to some value inside the $scope. Is there a way?

Comment: have you tried to put your value in a scope variable and the call it in the view like size="{{myselectSize}}" where myselectSize is $scope.myselectSize = 10; ???

Comment: @Sakuya84 I tried it, but didn't work. I think {{someValue}} is only valid inside ng attributes.

Comment: then the only thing i can think of is creating a simple directive for that...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `ng-size='10'` instead of `size`

That look like

```
<select  style='width:300px' ng-size={{size}} ng-model='selected' ng-options='k as v for (k,v) in options' />
```

js code

```
$scope.size=10;
```

**Edit**

As part of our effort to clean out old issues, this issue is being automatically closed since it has been inactivite for over two months.

Please try the newest versions of Angular (1.0.8 and 1.2.0-rc.1), and if the issue persists, comment below so we can discuss it.

**New Edit**

or You can do this way

```
data-ng-attr-size="{{some interpolated expression}}"
```

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/a1xLPGn2YeW0WavH2auD?p=preview

Thanks!

Comment: i don't think they implemented that yet...i couldn't find any documentation on the website

Comment: See my answer one more time

Comment: 'data-ng-attr-size' worked fine and easy to use. thanks

Comment: Why ng-size doesn't work but data-ng-attr-size works? Whats the different?

Comment: @Icet  because he's using lower version of angular.

Answer (score 0):

For me, ng-attr-size worked instead of size or ng-size.

The following will adjust the size of select to the length of the object named options.

```
ng-attr-size={{options.length}}
```

Comment: It works for me as well. Unfortunately this solution crashing in IE11