# How to set the height of a <select> element dynamically based on the number of item in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In Angular JS, I want to set the height of a `<select>` element based on the number of items in it so that I can see all the items in drop-down list without scrolling. I have tried using `ng-attr-size={{ctrl.length}}`, and I have tried using
    `data-ng-attr-size={{ctrl.length}}`, 
but to no avail... i am wondering if it has anything to do with when the angular is injected vs. the actual time the draw of the page is done....

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: really...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073532/in-angularjs-is-there-a-way-to-set-the-size-of-a-select-element-with-scope-va...   what am i missing to keep this as active, my code i have that does not function properly and want to have the proper code given to me to fix it....or a different name that way you do not know who is posting

Comment: SO I have updated this question, and now your team has revised it many times, can we allow this question to be answered now, please... thank you